# html span id as javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, arguments, zclip

I'm trying to create a copy to clipboard IE javascript function but my code isn't working.  How should I format my parameters and pass the argument?

```
/*invisible storage*/
<textarea id="storageBox" STYLE="display:none;">
</textarea>

<p id="abc">I WANT TO COPY THIS TEXT</p>

<button onClick="Copy(abc);">Copy</button><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function Copy(txt) {
storageBox.innerText = txt.innerText;
Copied = storageBox.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
</script>
```

Major karma for anyone who can write this using zclip or show me a similar example as well!!

Comment: Is your browser set up to allow access to the clipboard?

Comment: I allow script execution when I open the page in IE, yes.

Comment: Actually your script works fine. Just check your Internet Options to allow scripts to use clipboard.

Comment: @CptZpBrngn not scripts, clipboard access like previous comment mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes should help:

```
... onclick="Copy('abc');"...

storageBox.value = document.getElementById(txt).innerText
```

I think. You weren't very specific in saying what doesn't work or even for what reason you're trying to hijack the clipboard (what if the user has important stuff in there?)

Comment: Unfortunate this isn't working.  Does it matter that storageBox is also an id?  When I create a var using document.getElementById("storageBox") it still does nothing when I click the button.  I definitely agree that this is of poor form and would very much like to use zclip, but I'm very new to js.

Comment: Then I highly recommend finding a good book or an online tutorial before you ask questions on SO. Part of the policy for asking questions here is that you have to do your homework before asking for help. Also, if you need to read or write to a textarea, the syntax is [the textarea object].value, not innerText. The other answers here are also very valid - take them into consideration too.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass the parameter as a string:

```
<button onClick="Copy('abc');">Copy</button><br />
```

In your function, you need to get the element from the DOM based on this ID (as a string):

```
function Copy(txt) {
   storageBox.innerText = document.getElementById(txt).innerText;
   ...
```

Comment: This is the same as Art suggested and unfortunately isn't working.  Is there any way for me to run the code through a utility to pull up specific errors or warning?

Comment: Use Firefox, plus Firebug plug-in. Open the JS console and you should see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Though I commented your script working fine, there is something to fix in the `HTML`. If you set `display: none`, `execCommand()` can't copy the content. So you'll need to do this:

```
<textarea id="storageBox" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: This definitely gets the script working after properly changing parameters, but creates a pixel sized square.  Thank you for the info.

Comment: @CptZpBrngn You can position the `textarea` absolutely and set `top: -500px`. Though other answers guided you to pass arguments properly, your original script also works as is. In IE `id` creates a global variable referring to the element.